# Using minimumNumberShouldMatch in should query cannot get hits except its value is 1

Tags: boolean, elasticsearch

I used a query to search defined as follows:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = nestedQuery("bodyObject.drawElems",
            boolQuery()
                    .minimumNumberShouldMatch(1)
                    .should(matchQuery("bodyObject.drawElems.drawElemTitle", "problem engagement"))
                    .should(matchQuery("bodyObject.drawElems.drawElemTitle", "problem definition"))
                    .should(matchQuery("bodyObject.drawElems.drawElemTitle", "research"))
                    .should(matchQuery("bodyObject.drawElems.drawElemTitle", "problem resolution")));
```

when the value of **minimumNumberShouldMatch** is **1**, I got the excepted result.
But I changed it to be **2** or more, there is no hits any more, although I actually have docs which can meet at least two of should clauses, for example "problem engagement" and "problem definition".

Could anyone answer my question? Or is there something wrong with my codes ? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the explain api which might help understanding why a document doesn't amtch a query. Also, those different queries with different combination of words don't make much sense to me, can you explain what you want to achieve with the above query?

Comment: Using this BoolQuery I'd like to query a doc which contains multiple drawElems as Nested Objects and their different titles could meet the should clauses as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.  I would think the single nested query should be able to handle the multiple matches (rather than just one match), but for some reason the only way it worked is if I had a separate nested query for each value I wanted to match.  Hopefully you can transform this JSON query into a full object query like you have in your question.

```
{  
   "bool":{  
      "should":[  
         {  
            "nested":{  
               "path":"bodyObject.drawElems",
               "query":{  
                  "match":{  
                     "bodyObject.drawElems.drawElemTitle":"problem engagement"
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         {  
            "nested":{  
               "path":"bodyObject.drawElems",
               "query":{  
                  "match":{  
                     "bodyObject.drawElems.drawElemTitle":"problem definition"
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         {  
            "nested":{  
               "path":"bodyObject.drawElems",
               "query":{  
                  "match":{  
                     "bodyObject.drawElems.drawElemTitle":"research"
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         {  
            "nested":{  
               "path":"bodyObject.drawElems",
               "query":{  
                  "match":{  
                     "bodyObject.drawElems.drawElemTitle":"problem resolution"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match":2
   }
}
```